# How can I create a blank page and pass text in it using PyPDF2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pypdf

I was trying to extract data from pdf file finding the keys in data and replacing them with the values. Everything is working fine upto that mark but i don't know how to create stream of that new text and pass it in the blankpage

`def read_pdf():
text = ""
data = {
"Date": "23-3-4",
"Name": "haseeb",
"Title": "Route towards AK",
"Location": "Avenue 11",
"Route": "Route No 2",
"Area Manager": "Chris",
"Wages": "50.6",
"H&W": "10.5",
"OT Rate": "23.4",
"Gas Hourly": "56",
"Hourly Cell": "78"
}
with open("Payment Terms & Schedule.pdf", "rb") as pdf_file:

```
    pdf_reader = PdfReader(pdf_file)

    pdf_writer = PdfWriter()
    page = pdf_reader.pages[0]
    text = page.extract_text()
    matches = re.findall(r"\{\{(.+?)\}\}", text, re.DOTALL)
    new_page_text = text
    blank_page = PyPDF2.PageObject().create_blank_page(width=72, height=118)

    for match in matches:
        stripped_match = match.strip()

        if stripped_match in data.keys():
            new_match = data[stripped_match]
            new_page_text = new_page_text.replace("{{" + match + "}}", str(new_match))

    new_text = new_page_text
    new_page = PyPDF2.PageObject().create_blank_page(width=595.3, height=841.9)
    new_page._data_stream = new_text

    new_page.merge_page(page)

    pdf_writer.add_page(new_page)
    pdf_writer.add_page(new_page)

with open("new.pdf", mode="wb") as output_file:
    pdf_writer.write(output_file)
    output_file.close()`
```

Comment: Create the new pdf with `reportlab`, and use `PyPDF2` to extract and combine the pages/pdfs.

Comment: Please edit your question so that all of your code is formatted correctly. Thank you.